# Revisiting Functions In Python 3

Tags: python, function, memory, python-3.x

In my script I have four functions that work like this:

```
def function_four():
    # Does Stuff
    function_one()

def function_three():
    # Does Stuff
    function_two()

def function_one(): 
    usr_input = input("Options: '1') function_three | '2') Quit\nOption: ")
    if usr_input == '1':
        function_three()
    elif usr_input == '2':
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print("Did not recognise command. Try again.")
        function_one()

def function_two():
    usr_input = input("Options: '1') function_four | '2') function_three | '3') Quit\nOption: ")
    if usr_input == '1':
        function_four()
    elif usr_input == '2':
        function_three()
    elif usr_input == '3':
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print("Did not recognise command. Try again.")  
function_one()
```

I need to know if this will cause the problem I think it will: the functions never closing, causing lots of open functions (and, presumably, wasted memory and eventual slow-down) to appear, never to disappear until the user quits the script. If true, then this would most likely be bad practise and inadvisable, meaning that there must be an alternative?

Comment: Can we see the code instead of a verbal description of it? Also, what's the point of functions three and four?

Comment: @tzaman [Here is the simplified code](http://pastie.org/pastes/3422817/text). There are things going on apart from simply calling other functions, but they are not important to this question so I left them out for sake of simplicity.

Comment: This code just crashed my Python 3.2 -- and I don't mean a RuntimeException, I mean a genuine crash -- with a "Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow. Abort trap" message.  Admittedly I had to hold down the return key for a minute, but still.

Comment: @Eden: You can [edit] your question and directly replace your varbal description with your code. It's way more easy to understand real code then its description.

Comment: I edited the question for you Rik Poggi.
Tzaman: The last line is incorrectly aligned in my link, it should be to the far left, see the question for details.
DSM: Odd. Works for me. "include sys" is required for "sys.exit()" but apart from that I don't know what the problem could be.

Comment: @EdenCrow: oh, I know what the problem is-- it blew the recursion stack.  Ideally that should trip a runtime error, but apparently it's possible not to under certain circumstances.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whenever you have Python code that is:

> Recalling The Same Function So That If The User Does Not Chose One Of The Other Statements Then They Can Try Again Rather Than The Program To Stop Working,

you are almost always better off replacing the recursive call with a loop. In this case the recursion is completely unnecessary, probably wastes resources and arguably makes the code harder to follow.

**edit:** Now that you've posted the code, I'd suggest recasting it as a [state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). The following page provides a summary of Python modules that could be useful: [link](http://wiki.python.org/moin/FiniteStateMachine).

Even without any additional modules, your code lends itself to a simple non-recursive rewrite:

```
import sys

def function_four():
    # Does Stuff
    return function_one

def function_three():
    # Does Stuff
    return function_two

def function_one():
    usr_input = input("Options: '1') function_three | '2') Quit\nOption: ")
    if usr_input == '1':
        return function_three
    elif usr_input == '2':
        return None
    else:
        print("Did not recognise command. Try again.")
        return function_one

def function_two():
    usr_input = input("Options: '1') function_four | '2') function_three | '3') Quit\nOption: ")
    if usr_input == '1':
        return function_four
    elif usr_input == '2':
        return function_three
    elif usr_input == '3':
        return None
    else:
        print("Did not recognise command. Try again.")
        return function_two

state = function_one
while state is not None:
    state = state()
```

Note that the functions no longer call each other. Instead, each of them returns the next function to call, and the top-level loop takes care of the calling.

Comment: Also, whenever you have things like that, you'd better look up how uppercase and lowercase works in english. Also, when you have a language that supports tail call optimization, this doesn't hold true

Comment: @NiklasB.: With regards to learning to capitalize things correctly, the word *English* is spelled with an uppercase *E*. As to tail recursion, the question is specifically about Python.

Comment: "Touché" is what I'd have answered if it wasn't for that minimum comment size. Must have missed the [python] tag, as there was no Python code in the question o.O

Comment: Thanks for the advice aix, even if it does not answer my question.

Comment: @EdenCrow: Not sure if you've seen my edit, but I'd recommend rewriting your code as a simple state machine.

Comment: That's the kind of alternative I was looking for. Also: I did manage to find out elsewhere that the way of calling functions from functions in a way that never allowed them to close is fine.